# Calling 2 .toggle methods Swift UI

Tags: button, swiftui

How would I go about calling 2 toggles on one button. One pushes the new view and one hides a view on the main view.  `

```
                Button(action: {
                  
                    self.isPresentedPost.toggle()
                    self.showBottomSheet.toggle()
                    
                 }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "highlighter")
                    .font(.system(size:44, weight: .semibold))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color(ecGray))
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .padding(2)
                
                 })
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentedPost) {
                
                    UploadPostView()
                   

            }
                Text("Post")
                    .font(.system(size:12, weight: .semibold))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    
                
                        
            }`
```

Comment: What's happening right now that isn't working? Can you include a reproducible sample?

Comment: Its only calling the first toggle.